# How to create a new segmented offer without a segment name?

Tags: backend

I am trying to create a new segmented offer but without a segment name. Is this possible since it is marked with `*` as required to complete a new offer?
[image: click here to see image]

Comment: consider give more details and more tags to your question

Answer (score 0):

Currently when creating a segmented offer on the `STG` stack it requires the segmented name. If you create a segmented offer on any other stack, like `QA` or `PROD` it allows you to create it without a segmented name.